# On improving the upper bound $I(m^2) \leq \frac{2p}{p+1}$, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$

Tags: number-theory, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

(Preamble: This question is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3932623).)

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number (OPN) with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$, the *deficiency* of $x$ by $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$, and the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

Note that it is trivial to prove that
$$\frac{p+1}{p} \leq I(p^k) < \frac{p}{p-1}$$
from which we obtain
$$\frac{2(p-1)}{p} < I(m^2) = \frac{2}{I(p^k)} \leq \frac{2p}{p+1}.$$
This implies that
$$\frac{2}{p+1} \leq \frac{D(m^2)}{m^2} < \frac{2}{p}.$$
Taking reciprocals, multiplying by $2$, and subtracting $1$, we get
$$p-1 < \frac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} \leq p,$$
where we note that $(2/p) < p-1$.

Now consider the quantity
$$\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} - \dfrac{2}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} - \dfrac{2}{p}\bigg).$$
This quantity is **negative**.  Thus, we obtain
$$I(m^2) + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p}\bigg)^2 < \dfrac{2}{p}\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\bigg) = \dfrac{2}{p}\Bigg(\bigg(2-I(m^2)\bigg) + \bigg(\dfrac{I(m^2)}{2-I(m^2)}\bigg)\Bigg).$$
Now, let $z_1=I(m^2)$.  Then we have the inequality
$$z_1 + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p}\bigg)^2 < \dfrac{2}{p}\Bigg(\bigg(2-z_1\bigg) + \bigg(\dfrac{z_1}{2-z_1}\bigg)\Bigg),$$
from which we obtain
$$\dfrac{2(p-1)}{p} < z_1=I(m^2) < 2$$
using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+for+z+in+z+%2B+%282%2Fp%29%5E2+%3C+%282%2Fp%29%28%282-z%29%2B%28z%2F%282-z%29%29%29).

Here is my inquiry:

> **QUESTION:** In this [closely related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4197182), we were able to derive the improved lower bound
> $$\frac{2(p-1)}{p}+\frac{1}{pm^2}<I(m^2).$$
> Can we similarly derive an improved upper bound for $I(m^2)$, that is *hopefully better than*
> $$I(m^2) \leq \frac{2p}{p+1}?$$
> If we cannot, then can you explain why?

---

**MY ATTEMPT**

Consider the quantity
$$\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} - \dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} - \dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg).$$
This quantity is **nonnegative**.  Thus, we obtain
$$I(m^2) + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg)^2 \geq \dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\bigg) = \dfrac{2}{p+1}\Bigg(\bigg(2-I(m^2)\bigg) + \bigg(\dfrac{I(m^2)}{2-I(m^2)}\bigg)\Bigg).$$
Now, let $z_2 = I(m^2)$.  Then we have the inequality
$$z_2 + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg)^2 \geq \dfrac{2}{p+1}\Bigg(\bigg(2-z_2\bigg) + \bigg(\dfrac{z_2}{2-z_2}\bigg)\Bigg),$$
from which we obtain
$$\dfrac{4}{p+3} \leq z_2=I(m^2) \leq \dfrac{2p}{p+1},$$
using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve+for+z+in+z+%2B+%282%2F%28p%2B1%29%29%5E2+%3E%3D+%282%2F%28p%2B1%29%29%28%282-z%29%2B%28z%2F%282-z%29%29%29), which **does not improve on the previous known bounds** for $I(m^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *partial answer*.

(I merely wanted to collect, in one place, some recent thoughts that occurred to me, while I was pondering more on the problem in the original post.  As you can see, this is too long to fit in the **Comments** section.)

---

Consider the quantity
$$\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} - p\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} - p\bigg).$$
This quantity is **nonnegative**.  Consequently, we obtain
$$I(m^2) + p^2 \geq p\Bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\Bigg).$$
But it can be proven that the equations
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} = \dfrac{2\sigma(p^{k-1})}{\sigma(p^k)}$$
and
$$\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} = \dfrac{p^k}{\sigma(p^{k-1})}$$
hold in general.
These equations can be rewritten as
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} = \dfrac{2\bigg(\dfrac{p^k - 1}{p-1}\bigg)}{\dfrac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p-1}} = \dfrac{2(p^k - 1)}{p^{k+1} - 1}$$
and
$$\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} = \dfrac{p^k (p - 1)}{p^k - 1}$$
so that
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2}+\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}=\dfrac{2(p^k - 1)}{p^{k+1} - 1}+\dfrac{p^k (p - 1)}{p^k - 1}$$
which [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=FullSimplify%5B%28%282%28p%5Ek+-+1%29%2F%28p%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29%29%29+%2B+%28%28%28p%5Ek%29+%28p+-+1%29%29%2F%28p%5Ek+-+1%29%29%5D) expands to
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2}+\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}=\dfrac{p^{2k+2} - p^{2k+1} + 2p^{2k} - p^{k+1} - 3p^k + 2}{(p^{k+1} - 1)(p^k - 1)} := f(p,k).$$

But
$$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial k}=-\dfrac{p^k (p-1) \Bigg(p^k \bigg((p^2 - 2)p^k - 2(p - 2)\bigg) - 1\Bigg) \log(p)}{(p^{k+1} - 1)^2 (p^k - 1)^2} < 0$$
which means that $f(p,k)$ is a *decreasing* function of $k$.  This implies that
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2}+\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}=f(p,k) \geq \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}{f(p,k)}=\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\Bigg({\Bigg(\dfrac{2\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{p^k}\bigg)}{p-\dfrac{1}{p^k}}\Bigg)+\Bigg(\dfrac{p-1}{1-\dfrac{1}{p^k}}\Bigg)}\Bigg).$$
Since $p$ is a prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $p \geq 5$, so that
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty}\Bigg({\Bigg(\dfrac{2\bigg(1-\dfrac{1}{p^k}\bigg)}{p-\dfrac{1}{p^k}}\Bigg)+\Bigg(\dfrac{p-1}{1-\dfrac{1}{p^k}}\Bigg)}\Bigg)=\dfrac{2(1-0)}{p-0}+\dfrac{p-1}{1-0}=\dfrac{2}{p}+(p-1).$$

Hence, we obtain
$$I(m^2) + p^2 \geq p\Bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\Bigg) \geq p\Bigg(\dfrac{2}{p}+(p-1)\Bigg),$$
which results in the *trivial lower bound*
$$I(m^2) \geq 2 - p.$$

---

Again, consider the quantity
$$\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} - \dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} - \dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg).$$
This quantity is **nonnegative**.  Consequently, we obtain
$$I(m^2) + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg)^2 \geq \dfrac{2}{p+1}\Bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\Bigg).$$
Proceeding similarly as above, we get
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} \geq \dfrac{2}{p}+(p-1)$$
so that
$$I(m^2) + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p+1}\bigg)^2 \geq \dfrac{2}{p+1}\Bigg(\dfrac{2}{p}+(p-1)\Bigg)$$
from which we finally obtain
$$I(m^2) \geq \dfrac{2(p^3 - p + 2)}{p(p+1)^2}$$
which does not improve on the *previous known lower bound*
$$I(m^2) > \dfrac{2(p-1)}{p}.$$

---

Lastly, let us (again) consider the quantity
$$\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} - \dfrac{2}{p}\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} - \dfrac{2}{p}\bigg).$$
This quantity is **negative**.  Consequently, we obtain
$$I(m^2) + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p}\bigg)^2 < \dfrac{2}{p}\Bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\Bigg).$$
Proceeding similarly as above, since
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2}+\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}=\dfrac{p^{2k+2} - p^{2k+1} + 2p^{2k} - p^{k+1} - 3p^k + 2}{(p^{k+1} - 1)(p^k - 1)} = f(p,k)$$
is a decreasing function of $k$, and since $k$ is a positive integer satisfying $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $k \geq 1$, from which it follows that
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2}+\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}=f(p,k) \leq f(p,1)=\dfrac{2}{p+1}+p$$
so that we obtain
$$I(m^2) + \bigg(\dfrac{2}{p}\bigg)^2 < \dfrac{2}{p}\Bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\Bigg) \leq \dfrac{2}{p}\Bigg(\dfrac{2}{p+1}+p\Bigg)$$
from which we finally get
$$I(m^2) < \dfrac{2(p-1)(p^2 + 2p + 2)}{p^2 (p + 1)}$$
which does not improve on the *known upper bound*
$$I(m^2) \leq \dfrac{2p}{p+1}.$$

---

**Added: October 13, 2021 - 9:09 AM (Manila time)**

Consider the quantity
$$\bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} - (p-1)\bigg)\bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)} - (p-1)\bigg).$$
This quantity is **negative**.  Proceeding similarly as above, we obtain
$$I(m^2) + \bigg(p-1\bigg)^2 < \bigg(p-1\bigg)\Bigg(\dfrac{D(m^2)}{m^2} + \dfrac{\sigma(m^2)}{D(m^2)}\Bigg) \leq \bigg(p-1\bigg)\Bigg(\dfrac{2}{p+1}+p\Bigg)$$
which implies that
$$I(m^2) < \dfrac{(p+3)(p-1)}{p+1}.$$
This resulting upper bound is *trivial*, as it does not improve on the *known upper bound*
$$I(m^2) \leq \dfrac{2p}{p+1}.$$

---

**Alas, this is where I get stuck!**

Answer (score 0):

This is an *experimental attempt* - my apologies for any silly mistakes.

---

Since we have
$$I(m^2) \leq \dfrac{2p}{p+1}$$
and because $p^k m^2$ is perfect, then we have
$$I(p^k)I(m^2) = I(p^k m^2) = 2$$
where we have used the fact that the abundancy index function is *multiplicative*.

Hence, we obtain (via iteration)
$$\text{First iteration: } I(m^2) \leq I(p^k)I(m^2)\cdot\dfrac{p}{p+1} \leq 2I(p^k)\cdot\dfrac{p^2}{(p+1)^2} = \dfrac{2p^2\Bigg(p^{k+1} - 1\Bigg)}{p^k (p-1)(p+1)^2}$$
$$\text{Second iteration: } I(m^2) \leq 2I(p^k)\cdot\dfrac{p^2}{(p+1)^2}$$ $$= \bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^2 {I(m^2)} \cdot\dfrac{p^2}{(p+1)^2} \leq 2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^2 \cdot\dfrac{p^3}{(p+1)^3}$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
$$\ldots$$
by recursively replacing $2$ with $I(p^k)I(m^2)$ and then bounding $I(m^2)$ from above by $2p/(p+1)$.

Note that, at the $n^{\text{th}}$ iteration, we have the inequality
$$I(m^2) \leq 2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n \cdot \dfrac{p^{n+1}}{(p+1)^{n+1}}.$$
Repeating the process *ad infinitum*, we get
$$I(m^2) \leq \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\Bigg(2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n \cdot \dfrac{p^{n+1}}{(p+1)^{n+1}}\Bigg)} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}{\Bigg(\dfrac{2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n}{\dfrac{(p+1)^{n+1}}{p^{n+1}}}\Bigg)},$$
a limit which is of the indeterminate form
$$\dfrac{+\infty}{+\infty}.$$

Hence, we may apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), by separately considering
$$h(p) = \Bigg(\dfrac{2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n}{\dfrac{(p+1)^{n+1}}{p^{n+1}}}\Bigg)$$
as a function of $p$, and
$$j(k) = \Bigg(\dfrac{2\bigg(I(p^k)\bigg)^n}{\dfrac{(p+1)^{n+1}}{p^{n+1}}}\Bigg)$$
as a function of $k$.

(Also, note that there is "currently no L'Hôpital's rule for multiple variable limits".  The closest thing that I could find on arXiv is this [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.0363) by Gary R. Lawlor.)

I will stop here for the time being.

**Update: (October 13, 2021 - 11:37 AM) - Manila time** Since the denominator of $j(k)$ is strictly a function of $p$ and $n$, then there is no need to consider $j(k)$.

*Working on $h(p)$ now, will post an update in a bit.*

**Update: (October 13, 2021 - 12:27 PM) - Manila time** Cross-posted this answer as a question to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/406096), since the computations involved are somewhat tedious and complicated.